# Hide WooCommerce products if price is 0 or with no main image, from archives, widget and shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

The following code hides from WooCommerce archive pages, products which price is equal to zero or product without main image:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

But when I put a widget "Products" on home page, it will show all products, even if price is 0 or if they have no main image, what I don't want.
I tried to code this on myself without success.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

First, as you are making changes only to `meta_query`, `woocommerce_product_query` action hook can be replaced with `woocommerce_product_query_meta_query` filter hook…

Then you will be able to use the same function code for products **widget** filter hook (and even, if needed, for products **shortcode** filter hook.

The replacement code *(handles also products widget and shortcode)*:

```php
// For product archive pages (replacement hook and code)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_products_query_meta_query', 10, 1 );
// For products widget
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'filter_products_query_meta_query', 10, 1 );
// For products shortcode
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'filter_products_query_meta_query', 10, 1 );
function filter_products_query_meta_query( $query_args ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $query_args;
    }

    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    );

    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.